# Windows 10 Creators Update is breaking Borlands Database Desktop (Dbd32.exe)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 Creators Update is breaking Borlands Database Desktop. The program looks like it's starting and them immediately crashes. I've tried this now on 3 machines so far. Has anyone else seen this? And doesn't anyone know how to troubleshoot this type of issue? 
Ive tried... 
   A clean boot using MSConfig.
   Running in compatibility mode (All Windows versions tested).
   Ran Compatibility mode troubleshooter.
   Running it as an administrator.
Nothing worked.

Thanks

UPDATE: The "official" release just went live today and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you contacted the publisher of the software and reported the problem?  So you are aware, the Creators Update, has not been official released.  That happens on April 11th 2017.

Comment: MS has made the update available as an ISO starting today. And the publisher has long since stopped development on it. But it's a legacy product I still need to support.

Comment: If you have tried a compatability shim, then honestly, you have tried everything you can try outside of rolling back to the previous feature update.  I presume you have attempted to reinstall the application?

Answer (score 3):

Borlands Database Desktop and the underlying BDE engine were produced by Borland and have long been deprecated and don't ship with the latest Delphi and RAD Studio products. This has been the case for many years now. I don't think there is any plan to look into this very old technology -- and I work for the company.

Comment: I didn't expect help from the publisher really. Was more hoping someone has found a work around maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to confirm this issue, dbd32.exe does not start after Windows 10 upgrade to Creators Update. Fortunately rolling Window 10 back to Anniversary Update and deferring upgrades solved this problem for me. I'm going to test BDE under Creators Update better on my second computer and I will post my findings here.

Comment: This isn't an actual solution its a workaround, a workaround, that only will work for 4 months and only possible if your using Windows 10 Professional+

Comment: I have found and installed [Update Disabler](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1932) , that should prevent upgrade to Creators Update.

Comment: [Windows Update MiniTool](https://superuser.com/questions/1211389/avoiding-windows-10-creator-but-not-other-updates?rq=1) is so much better, you can hide current updates by clicking the "recycle" symbol, selecting "Functions update for Windows 10, version 1703" by scrolling to the bottom and by clicking ±H symbol.

Answer (score 0):

As Marco Cantù already stated, the BDE is depecrated. You can try if using an alternative BDE, e.g. [BDE eXpress](http://www.drregener.com/en/bde7.php) will work, otherwise you will have to rewrite that part of your application, or downgrade that machine to e.g. Windows 7 / 8.