# Windows 10 slow performance

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance

I am at my wits’ end with Windows 10 on my PC.

For the last couple of weeks after startup the PC runs extremely slowly. For example, it will take minutes to perform a button click event.

Now, I have tried the following:

1. Started in Safe Mode to check for errors – this is running fine
2. Made sure there is plenty of space
3. Turned off any unnecessary programs from start up and services
4. Changed Performance settings virtual memory and animation
5. Windows didn't give me the option to remove Creator Update from Recovery – I don’t know if this is anything to do with this version being an upgrade to Windows 10 from 8

None of these seem to work. I am reluctant to do a reinstall because I don't think I will have the opportunity to do a backup.

Does anyone have any idea of what I can do?

Comment: You only have 15 days to revert a feature update starting with 1703.  It has nothing to do with you upgrading from Windows 8.  Your installation is identical to a clean installation minus the fact you kept your user profile and installed programs

Comment: So do you have any idea why I am getting this problem then

Comment: Could you provide (Pastebin link will do) a list of drivers installed on your computer? http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_drivers_list.html might present it well.

Comment: try the steps from here: https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/96792-fall-creators-update-poor-performance-lagginess-fix.html

Comment: Made no difference. This was working before Creators went on. I have tried removing software, it can't do it, I can't do back ups. It will load fine and then grinds to halt

Comment: reinstall Windows with [1703 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557) and [hide the 1709 update](https://superuser.com/a/1211430/174557)

Comment: I did download an iso and made it bootable. However, when tried to install it I couldn't. There are two issues here: one my PC is UEFI and two  I cannot tell from the partition manager which partition is Windows 10 and the other my Linux distro

Comment: It is really running like a dog. After the first minute of startup it is fine but after that minute it takes minutes to run open a window, etc

Comment: [capture a boot trace and analyze it](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557) maybe the disk is busy at start and causes the delay for 1 minute. With Rufus you can create USb drives which are UEFI compatible.