# Prevent the Fall Creator's update from downloading automatically

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

For the last 4 days, Windows 10 has been trying to apply the Fall's Creator Update to my computer. After the first succesful update, I noticed the peformance of my PC went down considerably, so I rolled back to the previous Windows version.
However, next day, my PC started downloading the update on it's own again withotu my will, forcing me t0 update and roll back once again. This's been going on for the last 4 days and it's getting quite annoying to deal with.

Is there a way to stop Windows 10 from trying to apply this update, hopefully for good? I've got Windows 10 Home 1703 if it helps.

Comment: The reason windows was slow, was basically because it was catching up with updates that have been rolled out since the falls creators update came out.

Comment: use the [WIndows Update Minitool to hide the function update](https://superuser.com/a/1211430/174557)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say that Windows 10 Home has limitations when it comes to having your PC automatically download and install updates. It is not as flexible as Windows 7. Since you are new here, it would be helpful to know that Microsoft, which has been building Windows 10 under the service model (see their [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2017/07/27/waas-simplified-and-aligned/)) has two Windows Update timelines: "Semi-Annual Channel (targeted)" and "Semi-Annual Channel". The latter channel is intended for businesses and enterprises and only receives the latest updates only if they have not been through problems with the former channel, which is set by default and meant for general consumers. Windows 10 Pro and higher editions enables you to change between the two channels, but this is not possible with Windows 10 Home. Quoting from Microsoft:

> Home edition does not support the deferral of feature updates and will therefore typically receive a new version of Windows 10 prior to the end-of-service date shown.

That being said, it must also be noted that Microsoft will eventually stop releasing security updates for out-of-date versions of Windows. According to [this timeline page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet), your version of Windows will reach its end-of-support date this coming October. After this date, unless you update your PC to the latest version, you will not receive security updates for your PC. If you are having recurring problems with installing these updates, first try downloading and running Microsoft's Windows Update troubleshooter from [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter). If it does not help, there is an application called "Get Help" from the Start menu which you can click to contact the Microsoft Answer Desk. The technicians there will be happy to remotely connect to your PC to resolve your update issues.