# Install Windows 10 Pro 1703 and keep that

Tags: windows-update

We are running Windows 10 Pro x64. The Software we use only supports 1703.

So I have a new machine here, running 1607 and want to upgrade to 1703.

Also, I want to keep that, but install all other updates automatically. I know, that there will be one day I have to upgrade, but the vendor of the software we use should ship patches before that day.

Somehow, I didn't do any progress researching that, I wouldn't ask if I had any clue.

Thank you.

As I was asked where this is a duplicate of "How to disable Windows Updates": I would just disable them, if this was my intention. I want to stay on 1703. And as 1709 has been published half a year ago, it will still work.

Comment: It will depend a lot on how updates are managed in your environment but see if this helps: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-delay-windows-10-fall-creators-update-while-still-getting-security-patches

Comment: So you want to know how to upgrade from 1607 to 1703? Or you want to upgrade to 1703 and not go past that? From how your question is phrased I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Upgrade to 1703 then no further while still getting patches

Comment: 1709 was not released more than a year ago. That is the one that the OP wants to defer.

Comment: Be aware that MS is pushing updates to v. 1709 despite settings that *should have* deferred that: https://www.computerworld.com/article/3247754/microsoft-windows/reports-say-win10-creators-update-users-are-being-forced-to-fall-creators-update-again.html

Comment: Get the [1703 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO, run setup.exe and upgrade to 1703. Now run the [WIndowsUpdateMinitool to hide the offered 1709 update](https://superuser.com/a/1211430/174557) and stay at 1703.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll have a look at the minitool