# How to get Windows to stop reinstalling a failing update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, parallels

I am running Windows 10 in a Parallels VM. It's upgraded all the way from Windows 8 without issues over the years but the April 2018 update has failed repeatedly - each time I have to roll back to the previous version and each time Windows then notices I've not yet upgraded and goes into it's increasingly persistent reminder cycle which culminates in updating when I'm not looking.

Surely if an update isn't compatible for some reason, Windows Update should stop trying? Is this not the case?

This isn't a duplicate - I do NOT want to turn off Windows Update I want it to stop repeatedly installing something which keeps failing.

Comment: Only Microsoft can stop pushing an update to specific hardware, but only if they are aware of a specific configuration that is not compatible with an update, so you use the Feedback Hub to indicate that.

Comment: If I was in your current situation, I would [Pause the update](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) so that it will ensure [any pending update installations are canceled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb). After that, I would configure my machine to [defer Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) by selecting the Semi-Annual Channel. I configure all of the Windows 10 machines on my home network in that manner, and they never have any problems with Windows Updates.

Comment: this is a duplicate. [WindowsUpdateMinitool allows hiding of Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/a/1211430/174557)

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?